# Multiple SQL queries while calculating in C++

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-connector

I made an objective DB structure consisted of tables like: objects, types etc..
My program will be written in C++ and will make calculations on those objects.
My problem is that I have a large amount of different queries the program executes on the DB, since loading further objects is conditioned on former calculations.
Process is: loading objects >> calculations >> loading objects >> calc...
Every calculation determine what next set of objects/external info to load.

The ideal is writing a stored-procedure that will make the calculations. It is not possible because some of the calculations depends on external information.
I'm currently working with MySQL and the original MySQL C++ connector library. 
I am bothered with the predicted response times. Every cycle the SQL should parse & analyze the sql-query over and over again. Is there a faster way to access the DB? through API maybe? Can I write compiled 'SQL-procedures' with C++?
If you think I should use another DB rather than MySQL I would be glad to hear suggestions.

Thanks a lot.
Elad

Answer (score 0):

> If you think I should use another DB rather than MySQL I would be glad
>   to hear suggestions.

This depends on how much data do you need to store and how often do you need to access the data. In my experience, SQLite has been very useful as it is small and fast. As you are not using stored procedures and if your database requirement are not enterprise level, you should consider SQLite.

Before deciding alternative db system, I would strongly reckon to read threw follwing

- http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3632/3685825
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/sqlite-vs-mysql-vs-postgresql-a-comparison-of-relational-database-management-systems

Please do note following from http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

> Simplicity in a database engine can be either a strength or a
>   weakness, depending on what you are trying to do. In order to achieve
>   simplicity, SQLite has had to sacrifice other characteristics that
>   some people find useful, such as high concurrency, fine-grained access
>   control, a rich set of built-in functions, stored procedures, esoteric
>   SQL language features, XML and/or Java extensions, tera- or peta-byte
>   scalability, and so forth. If you need some of these features and do
>   not mind the added complexity that they bring, then SQLite is probably
>   not the database for you. SQLite is not intended to be an enterprise
>   database engine. It is not designed to compete with Oracle or
>   PostgreSQL.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Question here does not exist yet, last version from archive http://web.archive.org/web/20140915135851/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630/sqlite-vs-mysql/3632